# Google Social Login with Auth0 Tokens for [Authorized] API Calls

Tags: asp.net-web-api, auth0

Anyone here implemented social login through Google for Auth0? I have an issue with the tokens (access and id) being returned after validating with Google.

Here's my code:

```js
var waGoogle = new auth0.WebAuth({
  domain: 'testApplication.auth0.com',
  clientID: '************',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/'
})

waGoogle.authorize({
  connection: 'google-oauth2',
  responseType: 'id_token token'
  }, function(err, authResult){
    if(err){
      console.log('Google Login Error')
      console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Google screen shows up, I log in and I am redirected back to my application. From the application, I parse the URL so that I can get the access and id tokens.

```js
let getParameterByName = (name) => {
  var match = RegExp('[#&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.hash);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var access_token = getParameterByName('access_token')
var id_token = getParameterByName('id_token')
```

Issue I am having is that none of the tokens allow me to call my APIs (asp.net web api) which are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute. It returns a:

> 401 (Unauthorized)

I know that my API is working, as using the normal

> Username-Password-Authentication

method where I also obtain an access token, my api calls are just pulling through.

Are there any next steps which I need to do after obtaining the access and id_token from Google? Do I need to make an additional call to Auth0 to obtain the proper access token to be able to call my web api?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured the Google social connection with your own keys as explained [here](https://auth0.com/docs/goog-clientid).

Comment: Yes I did. I am able to obtain tokens (access and id) but the issue I am facing is that those tokens are not authorized for the APIs which I have decorated with [Authorized] for asp.net web api.

Comment: Is the access token you get a JWT token (a long string with three sections, separated by dots). If so, you can debug it in https://jwt.io and see how it differs from the one issued when using a database connection.

Answer (score 1):

The token you are looking for is called an IdP (Identity Provider) Token. This is different from the one issued to you after logging in. There are pretty good instructions on the Auth0 site that walk you through the process of getting that token.

[Here is the overview of IdP tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/idp)

[Here is a step-by-step guide to calling the Identity Provider](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/calling-an-external-idp-api)

The tl;dr:

To access the IdP token you need to call the Auth0 management API from your server. For that, your server will need a management token. Then use that token to access the endpoint **/api/v2/users/[USER_ID]**. In the object sent back from Auth0, look for the google identity and extract that token.

Also note, you should probably keep that token on your server if you can. If you can keep those power tokens away from your client your users will be happy.